# StaticArray with zero length

Tags: crystal-lang

How to make a static array of zero length for some type.

It's a little trivial problem but indeed unavoidable when writing some generic code like calling `give_me_some_names(names : StaticArray(String, N)) forall N` with empty names.

Of course, replacing with `Array` is a solution but if I just want `StaticArray`?

It's weird that I tried `uninitialized StaticArray(T, 0)` following the source code of `StaticArray` but the compiler cannot find method `uninitialized` here.

Comment: `StaticArray(T, 0)[]` also failed with message `undefined method '[]'`

Comment: I finally solved this by a really really dirty code : `StaticArray(T, 0).new { nil.as?(T).not_nil! }`

Comment: Why do you even need this? Oo

Comment: @bew, as I explained, I write some generic code like `foo(args : StaticArray(T, N)) forall N` expecting something usually, however in some special and rare cases I have nothing to send, which means sending empty StaticArray to the method, and this is unavoidable and the most natural.

Comment: like `disable_feature(StaticArray(String, 0).new)` means nothing should be disabled.